# QCompleter setModel crashes application

Tags: c++, qt

I have table widget, where one of the columns needs to have text autocopletion.

Each time the user request a new row I run this code for that column:

```
    else if (i == COLUMN_DESCRIPICION){
        QLineEdit *le = new QLineEdit(this);
        QStringList list = dbManager.getProductListStringsOnly();
        QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(list,le);
        completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
        completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
        le->setCompleter(completer);
        ui->twReceiptItems->setCellWidget(rowindex,i,le);
    }
```

So far so good. Now the user might need to input a new item to the system. If he does, then that Item also needs to be in the list of EXISTING rows. So to update the QCompleter word list I run this:

```
void MainView::updateProductList(){

    if (ui->twReceiptItems->rowCount() == 0) return;

    QStringList list = dbManager.getProductListStringsOnly();

    for (qint32 i = 0; i < ui->twReceiptItems->rowCount(); i++){
        qDebug() << 1;
        QLineEdit *le = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(ui->twReceiptItems->cellWidget(i,COLUMN_DESCRIPICION));
        qDebug() << 2 << (le == nullptr);
        QCompleter *completer = le->completer();
        qDebug() << 3 << (completer == nullptr);
        QStringListModel *model = static_cast<QStringListModel*>(completer->model());
        qDebug() << 4 << (model == nullptr);
        if (model == nullptr) model = new QStringListModel();
        qDebug() << 5 << (model == nullptr);
        model->setStringList(list);
        qDebug() << 6;
        completer->setModel(model);
        qDebug() << 7;
        le->setCompleter(completer);
        qDebug() << 8;
    }

}
```

The program crashes between qDebug line 6 and 7. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: where are line 6 and 7 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to replace the completer model using a pointer to its current one. When you call `setModel` a delete on the current object is called, and it happens to be the very same object you're trying to set as the *new* one.

Here you set a pointer to the current model:

```
QStringListModel *model = static_cast<QStringListModel*>(completer->model());
```

here you set it back:

```
completer->setModel(model);
```

Just use a new one, instead, i.e.

```
completer->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

or, even better

```
le.completer()->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

Just a footnote: don't use `static_cast` for up-casting. C++ has a specific cast for that, `dynamic_cast`, and Qt even has `qobject_cast` for QObject derivatives.